# I want records with clearence rate > 75. I can't use this in where clause, how should I do it?

Tags: sql

```
Select
suburb,round(100*count(case when result like 'Sold%' Then 1 else null end)/count(*)) 
AS clearence_rate
from sales 
group by suburb
order by suburb;
```

Comment: Have a look at `having`; your statement is also a syntax error with a missing argument for `round` and you don't need the *else* part as null is the default, and your expression will probably only return an integer any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the result of an aggregate expression you would do

```
Select suburb, <aggregate expression> AS clearence_rate
from sales 
group by suburb
having  <aggregate expression> > 75
order by suburb;
```

Answer (score 1):

There 2 opotion available.
First using CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
Select
suburb,round(100*count(case when result like 'Sold%' Then 1 else null end)/count(*))   as [value]
AS clearence_rate
from sales 
group by suburb
order by suburb
)
Select * from CTE Where [value] > 75
```

Second option using `HAVING` cluase:

```
Select
suburb,round(100*count(case when result like 'Sold%' Then 1 else null end)/count(*))   as [value]
AS clearence_rate
from sales 
group by suburb
HAVING round(100*count(case when result like 'Sold%' Then 1 else null end)/count(*))   > 75
```